# Can't get the documents by date Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have saved documents by `createdAt : new Date()`

These get saved as for example say "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-01-02T06:46:15.619Z"),

Now when I fetch the results by a single date using the query below it won't find.

```
User.find({
    "userStatus":"active",
    "entityType": {$ne: ""},
    "createdAt": {
        $gte: new Date(2017, 0, 2),//from date
        $lt: new Date(2017, 0, 2)//to date
    }},function(err,data){
        if(err){ ...
```

In my user model it goes like:

`createdAt:Date`

I am able to find for a broader range of dates but just not for a single date. 
I have tried `$lte` as well instead of `$lt`. All solutions on SO says the same thing. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Use new Date(Date.UTC(...)) with the same arguments for UTC time.  The variant you have has the date in local time zone.

Comment: Ok. While saving or while fetching ? if while saving, then how should I specify UTC there ? will new Date(Date.UTC()) work alone and save in UTC timestamp ?

Comment: Modified my search query to `"createdAt": {
                                $gte: new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 0, 2)),//from date
                                $lt: new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 0, 2))//to date
                            }` 
But didn't help

Comment: you have the same date  criteria in both `$gte` n `$lt`. This is equivalent to `ISODate("2017-01-02T00:00:00.000Z")`. The record you're trying to fetch has `ISODate("2017-01-02T06:46:15.619Z")`. Try to adjust your date. If you need single date comparison you've to add the time part to the query

Comment: True but practically I can only know the date and not the time to fetch that. What's the workaround in case my date filter has only one date or same from_date and to_date?

Comment: The only workaround I think it to save dates in db with time part set to all zeros. So this way the comparison is effectively dates only.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.User.find({ 
    createdAt:{
        $gte: ISODate("2016-11-16"),//from date
        $lte: ISODate("2016-12-01")}//To date
    }
);
```